# How can I display the value of it in the code .parseList{ DayForecast(HashMap(it)) } under Android Studio 3.0?

Tags: kotlin

The following sample code is from https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/antonioleiva/weatherapp/data/db/ForecastDb.kt

I hope to display the value of "it" in the code  `.parseList{ DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }`

So I set a breakpoint before the code `val dailyForecast ...`, and click *Run* -> *Debug 'app* menu in Android Studio, the press F7 to start Step Into, but I can't find how I can the value of "it" in the code  `.parseList{ DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }`

How can I do? Thanks!

```
override fun requestForecastByZipCode(zipCode: Long, date: Long) = forecastDbHelper.use {

    val dailyRequest = "${DayForecastTable.CITY_ID} = ? AND ${DayForecastTable.DATE} >= ?"
    val dailyForecast = select(DayForecastTable.NAME)
            .whereSimple(dailyRequest, zipCode.toString(), date.toString())
            .parseList { DayForecast(HashMap(it)) }

     val city = select(CityForecastTable.NAME)
            .whereSimple("${CityForecastTable.ID} = ?", zipCode.toString())
            .parseOpt { CityForecast(HashMap(it), dailyForecast) }


     city?.let { dataMapper.convertToDomain(it) }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a name temporarily:

```
.parseList { 
    val map = it
    DayForecast(HashMap(it)) 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but why can you insert " val map = it" before  DayForecast(HashMap(it)) ? I think that the App will be crash because the defined of parseList is parseList(parser: (Map<String, Any?>) -> T)

Comment: In fact, your code can run, but I don't know yet how to display the value of "it" using Android Studio , could you tell me the operation step using Android Studio to display the value of  "it"?

Comment: This is just so that you can look at `map` in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks! your code work, and more I can add any line before  DayForecast(HashMap(it)) , such as val map = 3,and I can see the value of it when I click Run -> Debug 'app' to start Debug the app